# Build graph (network) from vertices defined by an (x,y) position

Tags: graph

Is there an efficient way to build a network from a list of vertices that are defined by their (x,y) coordinates?

Algorithms or links to some examples would help.

Comment: that depends on how you want your vertices to be connected. are you going to have a bunch of points that need to connect to points that you tell it to or does it need to figure it out on it's own, if it needs to figure it out on it's own what will determine which it connects to (nearest, one that are one x or y value away, ect...)

Comment: @Jeff It needs to figure it out on its own. I came with a rough algo that will join all the right and left ones first, then join up/down/diagonal if they fit between the nodes in the other rows. It's a but messy, but I think that's the only way to do it

Comment: so for example take point (5,5)  that should connect to points (4,4), (4,5), (4,6), (5,6), (6,6) , (6,5), (6,4), (5,4) assuming they exist. is it possible for (5,5) to connect to (5,8)? point (5,5.5) was added what should happen?

Comment: @Jeff (5,5) should not connect to (5,8). Because there are other points inbetween. However, If (5,5.5) is added it has to split the link going between (5,6) and (5,5) and connect to: (4,6), (4,5), (5,5), (6,5), (6,6), (5,6)

Comment: what if you had something like (5.25, 5.5) added? how do you determine which node get removed when a closer one gets added. would (5.25, 5.5) brake the connection between (5,6) and (5,5) or (6,6) and (5,5)?